# How to set a value to elements in a column filtered by another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an `m X 3` matrix and an array of length m`.`
I want to do the following

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]])
b = np.array([1, 2, 1, 3, 3])
me = np.mean(a[np.where(b==1)][:, 0])
a[np.where(b==1)][:, 0] = me
```

The problem is that

```
a[np.where(b==1)][:, 0]
```

returns `[1, 7]` instead of `[4, 4]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are combining index arrays with slices:
`[np.where(b==1)]` is a index array, `[:, 0]` is a slice. The way you do it a copy is returned and therefore you set the new values on the copy. You should instead do:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]])
b = np.array([1, 2, 1, 3, 3])
me = np.mean(a[np.where(b==1)][:, 0])
a[np.where(b==1), 0] = me
```

Also see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html for combining index arrays with slices.